# How to check if a previous release has been completed before deploying a new release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As part of our release pipeline we have a task (the last task) to merge the release branch back to master.

I was wondering whether there is a way to check that this task or the previous release has completed before allowing the new release to be queued.  Can a gate be used for this?

Ideally, the release manager would then be able to decide whether they want to continue with the release or to cancel.

Comment: technically this is possible, one of the options for a release gate - is calling an azure function. then you'd need to code the function to check that and return ok or error depending on the outcome

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve your question? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the Invoke Rest API gate with an Azure DevOps API url because for checking the last release status you need to check the environment (stage) status, and for this, you need to the release id (so you can't know what it will be and put it in the rest API gate URL).

But, you can use PowerShell to check the last release and if it is not succeeded just fail the stage.

Add a PowerShell task in your release to check the last release:

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }

# Replace {org} with your organization
# Replace {project} with your project
# Replace {defId} with your release definition id

$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={defId}&api-version=5.1"
$releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'

$releaseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$($releases.value[1].id)?api-version=5.1"
$releaseInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $releaseUrl -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'

$releaseEvnriomentId =  $releaseInfo.environments.Where({ $_.name -eq 'THE STAGE NAME WHERE YOU DO MERGE' }).id

$envUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/$($releases.value[1].id)/environments/$($releaseEvnriomentId)?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$environment = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $envUrl -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'

$envStatus = $environment.status

if($envStatus -ne "succeeded")
{
    Write-Error "Previous release not succeeded!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Previous release succeeded :)" 
}
```

In the agent job options you need to allow scripts to access the OAuth token:

[image]

Azure functions also support PowerShell so you do it also with Azure functions gate:

1) Create a new Azure Function with VS Code like explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-powershell).

2) In your `run.ps1` file replace the code to this code:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$defnitionId = $Request.Query.DefinitionId

# Generate PAT and put it in the {YOUR PAT}
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,"{YOUR PAT}")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Replace {org} with your organization
# Replace {project} with your project

$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=$($defnitionId)&api-version=5.1"
$releases = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
Write-Debug $releases

$releaseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$($releases.value[1].id)?api-version=5.1"
$releaseInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $releaseUrl -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
Write-Debug $releaseInfo

$releaseEvnriomentId =  $releaseInfo.environments.Where({ $_.name -eq 'THE STAGE NAME WHERE YOU DO MERGE' }).id

$envUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/$($releases.value[1].id)/environments/$($releaseEvnriomentId)?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$environment = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $envUrl -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'
Write-Debug $environment

$envStatus = $environment.status
Write-Debug $envStatus

if($envStatus -ne "succeeded")
{
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
    $body = "failed"
}
else
{
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    $body = "success"
}


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

3) Publish the function to Azure.

4) Create an Invoke Azure Function gate in your release:

[image]

Another option, take the above code, convert him to C# or another language ans use Rest API, deploy to it web server and use the Invoke Rest API gate.