# How to prevent next Release pipeline in Azure Devops from starting, before previous one is fully finished?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm quite new to Azure Devops, so sorry if it's obvious questions.
I have a release pipeline with 3 stages like this:
[image: Release pipeline]

First stage is run on Agent A on Machine A, Stages 2,3 run on Agent B on Machine B.
Once stage 1 in prev. pipeline is finished -> it will start stage 1 of next scheduled pipeline run.
Is there a way to prevent this?  I would like to start next scheduled pipeline run only after all stages are finished in previous one.

Comment: I think it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709812/how-to-check-if-a-previous-release-has-been-completed-before-deploying-a-new-rel/58712024#58712024

Answer (score 0):

You can add Dependencies: If you are using YAML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

IF you are using classic pipelines you can use "Pre deployment Condition"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops

Also you can use approval gate if you want manual intervention.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using classing pipelines. I could not find anything in "Pre-Deployment condition" . Do you know which feature there could help me in m y case?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Specify queuing policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-queuing-policies), this is not currently possible except for using manual intervention.

> YAML pipelines don't support queuing policies. Each run of a pipeline
> is independent from and unaware of other runs. In other words, your
> two successive commits may trigger two pipelines, and both of them
> will execute the same sequence of stages without waiting for each
> other. While we work to bring queuing policies to YAML pipelines, we
> recommend that you use manual approvals in order to manually sequence
> and control the order the execution if this is of importance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post-Deployment approvals:
[image]

or Pre-Deployment approvals:

[image]